# how to get first value of duplicate value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I am having duplicates value also.

From that table, I want to get the first value of duplicate values via an order by id desc.

I am using below query to find count

```
select product_sku, quantity 
from catalog_product_store_inventory 
where ax_store_id=999 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

From this query, I get the all duplicates value.

I hope I made my query clear.

I am very new to MySQL.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a `LIMIT 1` Sorry you are not very clear about what it is you are trying to do

Comment: This query does not strictly **find a count** So do you actually mean you are looking for a count?

Comment: not count, suppose duplicate two value I want to get last value

Comment: So how do you define the LAST Value? The one with the largest `id`?

Comment: order by id desc; for duplicate value

Comment: Ok, so add `LIMIT 1` and you will only see that LAST row

Comment: no in this case i m getting only one value

Comment: @SarveshTiwari: please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What means duplicates in your case? Duplicates according to what `product_sku` or both `product_sku,quantity` - this should be used in GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT product_sku,quantity
FROM catalog_product_store_inventory c
JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(id) id
       FROM catalog_product_store_inventory
      GROUP BY product_sku
    ) m ON c.id = m.id
```

`ORDER BY id DESC` means that you want last ID from group and this one is MAX.

Comment: duplicate only product_sku, and what is c.id and m.id.

Comment: 'm' and 'c' are aliases for tables then c.id and m.id are columns from theses tables - these are SQL basics. Does this SQL solve your issue?